# Is it possible to read Devices from client system while using TCP Connection

Tags: c#, client-server, tcpclient, ip-camera

I have established connection with client system through socket in c# webapplication, in my connected client system i have connected PTZ ip camera thorough USB 3.0 cable. Is it possible to read camera informations from server system using TCP connection.

Comment: You can send client's camera informations to your server via tcp connection.

Comment: yeah Ok, but i have to access the camera from the server system, action like zoomIn,Out rotate Left,right

Comment: well, you need control infomations. Client make the corresponding operation when it receives control infomations.